# Yii CActiveDataProvider with class argument?

Tags: php, yii

I found this code at [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/157/keeping-a-running-total-in-a-cgridview/) website. What would have to be in the $dp dataprovider for the class TotalColumn to be called in the CGridView? Do I have to have the class TotalColumn be somewhere in $dp? Any idea how I would declare that CActiveDataProvider?

```
<?php
// protected/views/inventory/index.php

Yii::import('zii.widgets.grid.CGridColumn');

class TotalColumn extends CGridColumn {

private $_total = 0;

public function renderDataCellContent($row, $data) { // $row number is ignored

    $this->_total += $data->quantity;

    echo $this->_total;
}
}

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'dataProvider' => $dp,   // provided by the controller
'columns' => array(
    'id',
    'name',
    'quantity',
    array(
        'header' => 'Total',
        'class'  => 'TotalColumn'
    )
)));
```

Here is my code, but nothing in my custom column is displayed:

```
Yii::import('zii.widgets.grid.CGridColumn');
    class TotalSkills extends CGridColumn
    {
        private $test = "blah";

        public function renderSkills($row, $data)
        {
            echo $this->test;
        }

    }




// People
echo CHtml::label('People', 'yw0', $shared_html_options);
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Person');
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'columns'=>array(
                    'name',
                    'age',
                    array(
                    'header'=>'Total Skills',
                    'class'=>'TotalSkills'
                    ) 
                )
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create the TotalColumn class inside your protected/components directory as a TotalColumn.php file.  That way you can use it in many different view files, instead of the view file that is defined only. Yii will load it automatically then.

`$dp` should be a typical DataProvider class (more likely a [CActiveDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider)) that is defined in your controller and passed to your view.  The DataProvider can be as easy as the [CGridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView) documentation describes it.

Comment: See my problem is I pretty much copied this code verbatim, and my render function in my class (which is also just right above my CGridView with the Yii::import call) nothing is echoed. My table has a column I created with no output in any of the rows. I'll add the code I'm using in my original post.

Comment: As I said before, define your TotalSkills inside the protected/components dir.  This is how I define all my custom classes and I know it works.  I have no idea how it will behave if you define your class inside your view.  Why don't you do it in a clean and documented way?

Comment: Looking at your class again I see that you have not overridden the required "renderDataCellContent" method but you have defined your own "renderSkills".  This will NOT work.  Try renaming to renderDataCellContent....

Comment: Thank you. I eventually figured it out. Thanks for the tip on placing my class inside the protected/components directory. I have to have many classes like this so it definitely makes it way cleaner. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

> public function renderDataCellContent($row, $data)

is defined method in gridview 
but there is no method such as

> public function renderSkills($row, $data)

in gridview